# Why does a less than or more than comparison in PHP of two strings in the date format of "YYYY-MM-DD" work even though they are strings?

Tags: php, date, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I am working on a section of PHP code for a project that compares a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format to the current date to see if it is less than the current date. At different points in the code two different methods were used for making this comparison. The first used `get_timestamp()` on the dates and ran the comparison off of the timestamps. In another place it just compared the string of the date to the output from `date("Y-m-d")`. My expectation was that the comparison of two date strings would not provide a correct response. However, when I set up several test cases I got the output expected. I reviewed two parts of the PHP manual for insight and I am still confused as to why the comparison works without conversion to a timestamp.

The [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) section of the PHP manual states that the strings are either being converted to numbers and a numerical comparison is then made or that it makes something called a lexical comparison. I couldn't find anything further on lexical comparisons, but when I read about [string conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and tried the examples using date strings I get the same numerical output for each date string I try.

Can someone help me understand why a greater than or less than comparison of two date strings works (or at least appears to be working)? What am I missing?

As a follow up, if it really does work, I am assuming it is a better practice to convert the date to a timestamp and do the comparison based on the timestamp. Which is the better function to use for converting a date to a timestamp: `get_timestamp()` or `strtotime()`?

Sample code of less than / more than comparison of two YYYY-MM-DD strings:

```
if ("2013-06-27" < "2013-06-28") { echo "less"; } // Output: less
if ("2013-06-27" > "2013-06-28") { echo "more"; } // Output: (none)

if ("2013-06-29" < "2013-06-28") { echo "less"; } // Output: (none)
if ("2013-06-29" > "2013-06-28") { echo "more"; } // Output: more
```

Sample code testing numeric value of a converted YYYY-MM-DD string

```
$foo = 1 + "2013-06-27";
echo "\$foo==$foo"; // Output: $foo = 2014
$foo = 1 + "2013-06-28";
echo "\$foo==$foo"; // Output: $foo = 2014
$foo = 1 + "2013-06-29";
echo "\$foo==$foo"; // Output: $foo = 2014
```

Comment: "I am assuming it is a better practice to convert the date to a timestamp and do the comparison based on the timestamp" - why? i can't think of a reason this would be true. there's no problem with comparing string dates as long as they're formatted properly (YYYY-MM-DD or similar). to answer one of your questions, `strtotime` takes a string, while `get_timestamp` takes a `DateTime` object. so it depends. i find myself rarely using `DateTime` objects, as php has fantastic functions like `strtotime` to work with date strings.

Comment: I assumed using a simple less than or greater than comparison on two date strings wasn't best practice because every other example I have seen of date comparisons first converts it to a timestamp. It does seem like an extra step to convert it to a timestamp if you don't have to though.

Comment: Obviously because, if you remove the punctuation, they are... esentially `numbers` :) And you compare digits...

Comment: There are other good reasons to convert to timestamps, such as performing calculations (subtracting dates, adding/subtracting time periods) and dealing with timezone issues. But this property of comparisons is one of the reasons why this particular string representation is popular in computer applications.

Comment: Worth mentioning that, the reason you get `2014` in your above example expression is because, when an arithmetic operation is done on a string, PHP goes over your string looking for characters that pass `ctype_digit()` function and stops at first none digit char. So converting your above date to int returns `2013`, then 1 is added to give you `2014`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you compare a string this way, it will go from left to right, and compare each character in the given string to see if they are different, until it finds a difference, then it will decide which string is bigger by comparing the ASCII value of this last character. Coincidentally, since you are using only numbers, the highest numbers are also higher on the ASCII table.

This solution will work as long as you use only numbers in your comparisons, and that each string has the same number of characters

Also note that this works only since you are using the YYYY-MM-DD format, if you used another format it would not work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, is the comparison of each character from left to right what they mean by "lexical comparison?"

Comment: @PeterA - an old point, but yes. Note, numbers in LTR (left-to-right) languages are represented with the number of highest order of magnitude at the start (for example, hundreds before tens before units). Time is also usually represented in this way. However, most western date formats do not follow this same custom, where some (`m/d/Y`) actually follow no particular order of magnitude. This was corrected for ISO 8601. For general guidance on future comparisons, I advise using one of the DateTimeInterface classes.

Comment: But why dont the - characters interfere with the comparison?  Is it because they are equal in both strings?

Comment: @billrichards Yes

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DateTime` class for comparing dates. It makes it a lot easier to understand, and you don't have to deal with type juggling.