# PHP date time greater than today

Tags: php, date

please help what's wrong with my code? It always returns that today's date is greater than '01/02/2016' wherein 2016 is greater than in 2015.

```
<?php
$date_now = date("m/d/Y");

$date = date_create("01/02/2016");
$date_convert = date_format($date, "m/d/Y");

if ($date_now > $date_convert) {
    echo 'greater than';
} else {
    echo 'Less than';
}
```

P.S: 01/02/2016 is coming from the database.

Comment: Use timestamps to compare dates. Strings are highly unreliable for that task as you have seen.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You are *not* comparing dates. You are comparing *strings*. In the world of string comparisons, `09/17/2015` > `01/02/2016` because `09` > `01`. You need to either put your date in a comparable string format or compare `DateTime` objects which are comparable.

```
<?php
 $date_now = date("Y-m-d"); // this format is string comparable

if ($date_now > '2016-01-02') {
    echo 'greater than';
}else{
    echo 'Less than';
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LU115)

Or

```
<?php
 $date_now = new DateTime();
 $date2    = new DateTime("01/02/2016");

if ($date_now > $date2) {
    echo 'greater than';
}else{
    echo 'Less than';
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5rQVP)

Comment: $date_now = new DateTime();
$sql = "UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no' WHERE strduedate > '$date_now' ";

Comment: strifoverdue is in VARCHAR type. how can i convert it to date and perform my query? TY!!

Comment: sorry i mean strduedate is in VARCHAR type meaning im comparing strings and date. i have no idea how to convert strduedate to DATE type in m/d/Y format

Comment: What's going on that makes '2016-01-02' a comparable date format?  Casting '2016-01-02' to int or float returns 2016.  Yet, ( '2016-01-02' < '2016-01-03') is true.

Comment: I think this is the explanation.  PHP is not casting the string.  It's comparing each character in the string https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371819

Comment: @user9437856 I have updated the links to work again. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @JohnConde, Yes, this post is old but still working for me. upvote from my side.

Answer (score 12):

We can convert the dates into timestamps to compare

```
<?php

    $date_now = time(); //current timestamp
    $date_convert = strtotime('2022-08-01');

    if ($date_now > $date_convert) {
        echo 'greater than';
    } else {
        echo 'Less than';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dates could be in different formats, so it is better to convert them to timestamps before comparison

```
<?php
 $today = date("Y-m-d"); //Today
 $date = '2022-06-30'; //Date

 if (strtotime($today) > strtotime($date)) {
    echo 'Today is greater than date';
 }else{
    echo 'Today is less than date';
}
```

Comment: It would be so much better if you explained your code as well.