# Check if date isn't greater than today

Tags: php, date, yii2

I want to check if my date isn't greater than today. I write this code but it isn't work:

```
public function getDate() {
    $month = $this->month;
    return $this->year . '-' . $month . '-' . $this->day;
}

public function getDbFormatedDate() {
    if (checkdate($this->month, $this->day, $this->year) || $this->strtotime(getDate())>strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){
        $dateDeadline    = date_create($this->getDate());
        $this->BirthDate = date_format($dateDeadline, 'Y-m-d');

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Zmiany w profilu zostały zapisane'));
    } else {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'nie ma takeij daty');
    }
}
```

Comment: To attract the right audience, it would be useful to tag this with whatever language that is.

Comment: this is in php in Yii2

Answer (score 2):

Use CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

This should do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

It is better to compare two [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. Get inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642436/2709029

```
function isFuture(DateTime $futureDate)
{
  return ($futureDate > new DateTime) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Review from [xCrZx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1525629/xcrzx):

```
function isFuture(DateTime $futureDate)
{
  return $futureDate > new DateTime;  // comparison results in boolean
}
```

Obviously, the ternary operator is redundant. This review was rejected by others and I cannot accept it by myself, although I consider it smarter than my code. So I post it here this way. Anyway, credits go to xCrZx.